# C++11 implicit move constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, object-lifetime, move-constructor

I'm having trouble understanding why the following (at least according to gcc 4.8) is legal in C++11:

```
// This class manages a non-copyable resource.
struct B {
  B();
  B(B &&) { /* logging, etc., to verify if needed. */ }
private:
  B(B const &);
  B const &operator=(B const &);
};

B bar() {
  B b;
  // This is apparently allowed via the move constructor.
  return b;
};

int main() {
  // From this "side" of the call as well.
  B b1 = bar();
  B b2{bar()};
}
```

In what contexts are move constructors allowed or actually preferred by the language? Temporary return values seem fair to move (and trash contents of), but I'd like to find the core language rule for all places where the move can be silently used. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, there's nice new `delete` keyword: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions

Comment: *"but I'd like to find **the** core language rule for all places where the move can be silently used"* There's not *one* rule, but several. The "most obscure" is returning a local variable / a parameter, with certain restrictions. Besides that, rvalues are moved (you'll need to look up what an rvalue is in C++11).

Comment: @dyp Do you happen to at least have the spec general section handy? I'd be willing to slog through a lot of the reading as long as it wasn't a blind search.

Comment: @Jeff I think section 3 and 12 will cover how `rvalues` can bind.  I think you're probably most interested in `prvalues`.

Comment: @Jeff As Jason said; I'd narrow that down further to 3.10 [basic.lval] describing *what rvalues are*, 8.5.3./5 [dcl.init.ref] *which initializer-expressions can bind to an rvalue*, 12.8 [class.copy] *when is a move constructor implicitly generated* and 12.8/32 *a special rule for return-statements* and finally 13.3.3.2/3 [over.ics.rank] *overload resolution between rvalue refs and const lvalue refs*. That should cover *most* situations, but might be hard to understand. Maybe reading some article or book on that topic might be a better idea.

Comment: I agree with @dyp.  I think the standard is more for implementing a compiler.  Bjarne Stroustrup's [latest book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) covers a lot of the same material but it's a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

A move can be used by the compiler whenever the argument binds to an `rvalue` reference.  It's used by the compiler whenever the argument is a `prvalue` (see below).  Arguments can also be casted to `rvalue` reference.

In general, rvalues are anything that appears on the right side of an assignment.  A rough way to think about it is in terms of whether it can be referred to in the code.  lvalues have identity, rvalues *generally* don't.

Really, there are a few types of lvalues, and rvalues...

- `lvalue` - has identity, can't be moved (`lvalue`)
- `xvalue` - has identity, can be moved (`lvalue` and `rvalue`)
- `prvalue` - has no identity, can be moved (`rvalue`)

An `xvalue` is both an `lvalue`, and an `rvalue`.  An example would be something that you explicitly cast to an `rvalue` reference using `std::move`.

Comment: This does not cover the case of return values.

Comment: The return values depend on the context of the call.  If you look at the above example, the value returned from `bar()` doesn't have identity, and is moveable (`prvalue`).

Comment: Hmm I haven't expressed myself clearly, sorry. In a return-statement, named variables (lvalues) can also be moved with some restrictions (Essentially, it's an alternative to NRVO, when NRVO itself cannot be / is not applied.)

Comment: Exactly, the identity is scoped to the function.  At the call site, assignment/construction, it doesn't have identity.  If there were a move-assign `B& operator=(B&& b)`function, it would move for both copy and assign.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean with that last sentence ("If there were a move-assign ..."). In the context of return-statements, a variable that *has* identity and *is* an lvalue is *treated as an rvalue* to move it out of the local scope. This is an additional rule to the general *rvalues are moved but lvalues are not*.

Comment: Specifically, the returned value is treated as a `prvalue` in the overload resolution for initialization/assignment.  It could also be move-elided/copy-elided depending on a lot of other criteria (non-trivial constructor, etc...).  The class doesn't have a default move-assignment function since there's a user defined copy and copy-assign which prevent default move-assign from being generated.  If it were explicitly defined though, the `prvalue` would also be moved in assignment in addition to initialization.  Generally `prvalues` move, but there is a *lot* that determines so.

Answer (score -1):

Also, there's a nice intro to rvalue references and move semantics http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

Comment: Links are not answers.  Links can complement answers.